# Model automatically saves into a " (modelname)+s " collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose (last version , fresh install) for a MEAN architecture (mongo+express+angular+nodejs) and i'm approaching to save some data into my mongodb.
I have a db called "cogestione" and three collections: "ragazzi", "sedi" and "corsi".
I want to save a data of type Ragazzo in collection "ragazzi". I connect with:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin:************.mongodb.net/cogestione?retryWrites=true", { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log("Connection to database correctly happened"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

and all goes smoothly. In another file i have the model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    nome: {
            type: 'String'
        },
        cognome: {
            type: 'String'
        },
        classe: {
            type: 'String'
        },
        email: {
            type: 'String'
        }
  }
  );
```

module.exports = mongoose.model("ragazzo" , postSchema);

and i export it with the last line. Then , back in the app i send it to the db with:

```
const post = new Ragazzo({
    nome: req.body.nome,
    cognome: req.body.cognome,
    classe: req.body.classe,
    email: req.body.email
  });
  console.log(post);
  post.save()
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
  res.status(201).json({message : "Post added"});
```

The problem is that it doesn't save my doc into "ragazzi" collection , but it creates a new collection called "ragazzos"... how can i tell mongoose to save it into a fixed collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your mongoose Schema like as bellow.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    nome: {
            type: 'String'
        },
        cognome: {
            type: 'String'
        },
        classe: {
            type: 'String'
        },
        email: {
            type: 'String'
        }
  }, {collection: 'ragazzi'});
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is you use this line

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("ragazzo" , postSchema);
```

but not export the compiled model.. you should export the compiled model like this

```
const Post = module.exports = mongoose.model("ragazzo" , postSchema);
```

then in your router import it like so

```
const post = require("./models/Post"); // in your case keep your file path 


const post = new Post({
    nome: req.body.nome,
    cognome: req.body.cognome,
    classe: req.body.classe,
    email: req.body.email
  });
  console.log(post);
  post.save()
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
  res.status(201).json({message : "Post added"});
```

this will work the way you want it mate .. cheers

Comment: i did what you wrote, just forgot to mention that lines of code. The problem has been solved by another user who told me to add a third parameter in .model() that's the collection name. Thanks anyway